# Draw part of path without stroke, part with stroke

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am drawing a path using the `canvas` element and `JavaScript`

The path has a fill, and a stroke. I however would only want to apply the stroke to parts of the path.

I have created a JSFiddle which shows the shape I have been drawing, with comments explaining which parts should or should not be stroked.

http://jsfiddle.net/DanielApt/22973/

How can I make parts of the path have no stroke?

I have been using:

```
function draw() 
{  
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");  
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
    ctx.lineWidth = 3;
    ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';

    ctx.moveTo(10, 200); // the starting point

    ctx.lineTo(10, 150); // I want this to have no stroke
    ctx.lineTo(110, 30); // stroked line
    ctx.lineTo(210, 50); // stroked line

    ctx.stroke(); // end our stroke here


    ctx.lineTo(210, 200); // line without a stroke
    ctx.fill();
}

draw();
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only get 1 styling between beginPath() and fill()/stroke().

So to get a path that optionally strokes its segments you must:

- Draw each segment individually and either apply a stroke or not.
- Redraw the whole path and fill it.

BTW, You should begin all path drawing commands with context.beginPath().  If not then all drawings since the last beginPath will also be redrawn during every stroke/fill.

Here's example code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var points=[];
    points.push({x:10,y:200,isStroked:false});
    points.push({x:10,y:150,isStroked:false});
    points.push({x:110,y:30,isStroked:true});
    points.push({x:210,y:50,isStroked:true});
    points.push({x:210,y:200,isStroked:false});
    points.push({x:10,y:200,isStroked:false});

    draw(points,"red","blue",3);

    function draw(points,stroke,fill,linewidth){
        ctx.strokeStyle=stroke;
        ctx.lineWidth=linewidth;
        ctx.fillStyle=fill;

        // draw strokes
        for(var i=1;i<points.length;i++){
            var p=points[i];
            if(p.isStroked){
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(points[i-1].x,points[i-1].y);
                ctx.lineTo(points[i].x,points[i].y);
                ctx.stroke();            
            }
        }

        // draw fill
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(points[0].x,points[0].y);
        for(var i=1;i<points.length;i++){
            ctx.lineTo(points[i].x,points[i].y);
        }
        ctx.fill();
    }

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The real solution for me was two draw two seperate paths, one for stroke, and one for the fill! Also I learnt something re `beginPath()`. Once again, thank you!